# C++ error - C2228, identifier not recognized as class

Tags: c++

Here is the relevant code:

Canvas.cpp

---

```
    #ifndef CANVAS
    #define CANVAS

    #include "graphicsDatatypes.h"

    class Canvas
    {
    private:

        // Current and next points to draw to
        struct cartesianPoint currentPoint, nextPoint;

    public:

        Canvas::Canvas() { numLinesDrawn = 0; };
        Canvas::~Canvas();  

        struct cartesianPoint getCurrentPoint() { return currentPoint; };

        void setCurrentPoint(int x, int y)
        {
            currentPoint.x = x;
            currentPoint.y = y;
        }


    };

#endif
```

---

main.cpp

---

```
#include "glut-3.7.6-bin\glut.h"
#include "Canvas.cpp"

// Window size
int winWidth, winHeight;

// User's drawing space - current maximum of 4000 lines
Canvas userDrawSpace();

void callbackMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    userDrawSpace.setCurrentPoint(x, y);
}
```

---

The error I am getting is - error C2228: left of '.setCurrentPoint' must have class/struct/union

Any idea why? The class is pretty clearly defined, and include should simply be bringing in the text. Visual studios recognizes that Canvas is a class when I hover over it with my mouse, so I have no clue what's going on. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Canvas userDrawSpace;` rather than `Canvas userDrawSpace();`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
Canvas userDrawSpace();
```

looks like it should be creating Canvas object, but in fact it declares a function called userDrawSpace returning a Canvas object :-(.

That's a very common gotcha in C++.

Just get rid of the () and it should be ok.

Comment: As far as I know globals are not created on the stack

Comment: well, I meant as opposed to the heap, but I guess you're right. I'll edit it.

Comment: This subtlety even has its own name: [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: Thanks. I come from a mostly Java/C background, so the syntactical specificities of C++ are giving me a lot of trouble. Thank you for your help!